# Python runs regex on variable but not on file with same content

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a python (2.7) script to parse some logs from a java application using regex.
I used http://pythex.org/ to help test the patterns and they work there with a reduced log sample just fine.

Once I do the same on my script it works if I put some of the log in a variable, but wont work if I point it to a file.

Here is the code

```
import re
regex_sql_java_error = "\[use.(.*?)\]\nThread:.{9}(GENERAL|LOADER).{17}(ERROR(.*?)\n)"
logfile = open('example_files/Log_file.txt', 'r')
data = logfile.read()
logfile.close()

filtered = re.finditer(regex_sql_java_error, data, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
if filtered:
    for item in filtered:
        print item.group(0)
```

The logfile I am using is a measly 1MB file.

I can't imagine the pattern being the issue, but heres a sample of the log file that matched just fine on pythex.org

```
Thread:    5624 LOADER 08:26:37.078     INFO  executeDdlStatements:
[use ADMINI;, SOME BROKEN SQL HERE;]
Thread:    5624 LOADER 08:26:37.086    ERROR  'executeDdlStatements' command failed with the error: Table 'ADMININTT' doesn't exist
                                RANDOM JAVA STUFF
```

Link to it on pythex http://goo.gl/mZSx4z

I've been bashing my head on this for a couple days, read a bunch of docs, but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Hopefully its something really stupid Ill be able to laugh about later.

Anyway, if anybody can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Your code works OK for me... file encoding?

Comment: Dumb me, file came from windows, changed \n to \r\n and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This was dumb and fast, and like I thought, I can laugh about it now..

Logfiles came from windows, substitute \n for \r\n everywhere and be happy!

Comment: Isn't there a way to open file with universal newlines? That rings a bell, but I don't recall offhand. Might be worthwhile incase files ever start coming from *nix (`\n`) or MacOS (`\r` maybe?)

Comment: If there is a way it would be awesome. I coded a simple os detection using os.name and I changed the regex when running on windows to get over that.